# Rewiring USB connector on Asus Transformer

Tags: usb, soldering

[image: Broken USB connector]

My Asus Transformer USB port has broken several times, so the connector itself is now damaged due to the soldering. My only option is to cut the wire and connect it to one of my unused USBs, but their wires are different.

How do I connect a red, orange, yellow, green and white wired USB connector to a yellow, blue, brown and red wired USB connector?

[image: Close-up of cables]

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you have four or five wires that you're trying to connect to a four-wire USB connector (as far as I know, USB only uses four). Please edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: yup!!! that's what i can see here...but the red and orange wire is soldered together here in the usb of my asus...so is it okay if i connect the orange and red one to the red wire of the other usb connector?

Comment: Your 'unused USBs'?  What do you mean by that?  USB is a type of interface.

Comment: @Paradroid They obviously mean a spare connector from a different USB device. Explaining technical language isn't going to help, especially when you use even more technical terms to do it.

Answer (score 4):

here's the standard pinout colour code for a 1.x/2.0 connector (borrowed from Wikipedia)

```
Pin    Name

1  VBUS    Red +5 V

2  D−  White(Gold *)   Data −

3  D+  Green   Data +

4  GND   Black(blue*)    Ground
```

.- D+  D- +

**.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.**

**|========|**

4  3   2   1

NB ..but you'd be missing the 5th USB pin line from the asus charge cable to tell it to switch to 15V charging instead of 5V. Though a fix can seemingly be made by grounding the 5th (pin7) wire of the Asus USB 3 connector using a replacement USB 2.0 (bridged/soldered over to pin 4 as above), you'd be best to use a USB 3 connector/ cable if you have one. See this link http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1087321

Comment: And how it's possible to identify the original cables?

Answer (score 4):

[This page has the full diagram](http://thecenk.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/usb-3-0-data-charger-cable-for-asus-eeepad-tf101-tf201-sl201-wiring-diagram/) that shows which wires go where.

[image]

Worked great for me, i just finished fixing mine. Putting on some cheap +2 reading glasses greatly help this microscopic task. Good luck!